# Is it a good idea to allow ONLY 'sign in with' google/facebook/twitter in my site?

Tags: authentication, google-signin, signing

I was thinking to allow users only to log in with an already existing google/facebook/twitter account (this would save a lot of time and safety concerns) and no ability to sign up as a user to the website properly. Do you think this is reasonable? Or definitively a bad idea/too limiting?

Comment: How about just using something like Firebase, it will support a variety of options and you don't need to worry about the implementation / security / maintenance? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth

Comment: Well I already started with MERN stack, and I have profiles etc saved as MONGO objects, do you think I should migrate to firebase?